# jQuery UI : making an element both draggable AND sortable within the same parent element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jQuery UI to create a Schedule manager widget that allows the user to resize and sort time-slot elements for a given day. Each time-slot has a duration, which is represented by its height, and a start / end time which is calculated based on its order in the stack and its duration.  "Gaps" in the schedule are represented by placeholder elements, with their height equating to the gap-duration.

Right now a user can modify a time-slot's duration by resizing it (which inversely sizes adjacent placeholders, if any), or they can change its start / end time by sorting it in relation to the other time-slots / placeholders.

I would like to also make each time-slot element draggable, so that a user can manually position the element within the day column, at which point its correct start-/end-time would be calculated along with any other necessary changes (such as adding new placeholders or splicing existing time-slots)

However, when I try to combine the two widgets together, I run into some weird UI bugs and inconsistent behaviors.  Please see the following fiddle for a rough example...

http://jsfiddle.net/SETTM/16/

Can anyone tell me if I am going about this the right / wrong way, or if this is even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what weird UI bugs and inconsistent behavior you are experiencing? I see no reason why this shouldn't be possible and your jsfiddle is working fine for me.

Comment: there are a couple of issues (which are all sporadic)...1. when dragging an item via the red "handle", items in the list "stutter" / "flicker" / "jump" as I move the dragged item around. 2. sometimes the position of the dragged item changes so it is a several hundred pixels away from the mouse pointer (this can make it disappear if this makes it fall "outside" the parent container. 3.  Which events fire / trigger, and in which order (ie draggable-start vs sortable-start) appear to happen inconsistently from one interaction to the next...